# SvelteKit: How to prevent a pages content to load when redirecting?

Tags: sveltekit

I have a sveltekit website with a page whose content I want to protect and hide unless you are logged in.
I protect the route by redirecting to the login page in the `+page.server.ts` if the user isn't logged in. That looks something like this:

```js
// src/routes/protected/+page.server.ts

import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { hash } from '../../../utils/hash';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
 
export const load = (async ({ cookies, url }) => {
    if (cookies.get("pwd") !== hash("password")) {
        throw redirect(307, "/login");
    }
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

If I now try to open `https://domain/protected` without being logged in I get instantly redirected and don't get to see the content of the page.

My problem is: Even though the page should not have have been loaded because I redirected the request already on the server I can find the `+page.svelte` in the debugger of the browser and one can easily open it and read the text of the page. It ends up under `https://domain/_app/immutable/components/pages/protected/_page.svelte-12345678.js`.

`export const prerender = false;` and `export const ssr = false;` don't help.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Client code cannot really be restricted as of now, to my knowledge. This is not a simple thing to change either due to code splitting. I saw an issue about this but could not find it right now.

Would recommend injecting any restricted content from the server, rather than putting it directly into the page.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. That was the only thing I could think of rn too...